# How to merge two arrays of in Javascript de-duplicate items and sum their quantities

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have two JavaScript arrays:

```
const array1 = [
  {id: 01, qnty: 2}, 
  {id: 02, qnty: 1}, 
  {id: 03, qnty: 1}
];

const array2 = [{id: 02, qnty: 3}];
```

I want the output to be:

```
const newArray = [
  {id: 01, qnty: 2},
  {id: 02, qnty: 4},
  {id: 03, qnty: 1},
];
```

The output array should have removed items with same `id`, and sum their `qnty` values.

Comment: I did not downvote, but questions which are (looks like) homeworks are off-topic. You should provide a code sample of what you have at the moment and point out where you have difficulties.

Comment: Is it not clear enough?

Comment: It's not that it's not clear enough, it's that you seem to not have tried at all and are asking SO to do your job/homework.

Comment: From the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Comment: I've been trying for a while, just can't seem to find the correct order of methods to use for this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function inArray(arr, obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id == obj.id) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}


const array1 = [{  id: 01,  qnty: 2}, {  id: 02,
  qnty: 1}, {  id: 03,  qnty: 1}];



const array2 = [{  id: 02,  qnty: 3}];

var newArray = array1.slice(0); //clone array1
for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  var obj = array2[i];
  var index = inArray(array1, obj);
  if( index== -1){
     newArray.push(obj);
  }else {
    newArray[index] = { id: newArray[index].id,  qnty: newArray[index].qnty + obj.qnty } 
  }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

```html
const newArray = [ {id: 01, qnty: 2}, {id: 02, qnty: 4}, {id: 03, qnty: 1}, ];
```

Comment: Now extend that to handle three or four or any number of arrays. And can you think of a way to make it both simpler and faster for lengthy arrays? (Hint: use a temporary object with each `id` for the property names.)